# How to access a newly mounted DMG from VMWare Fusion (Windows 8.1)?

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization, mount, dmg

I'm running Windows 8.1 on VMWare Fusion, on top of OS X 10.8.5.

I have some DMG files on Mac that I mount sometimes to work with.
These are some encrypted data folders.

Can I access them from the virtual machine when I mount them?

Example: VM is running, Windows is running inside. Then I go to MacOS and mount a DMG. Next moment, a new drive (or folder) appears in Windows... without needing to restart the virtual machine.

Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible without some special software in the windows vm. The dmg  is analogous to the windows .exe.  In the same way a Mac can not run an .exe, a windows box can not open a dmg.  That being said a software solution like transmac installed in the vm may offer the functionality you seek.

No personal experience with transmac myself.

http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm

Trasmac features:

-Open Mac format disk drives, flash drives, CD/DVD/Blu-ray media, high density diskettes, dmg and sparseimage files.

-Copy files to Mac disks and dmg images.

-Format for Mac and restore disks and flash drives.

-Create, compress and expand (convert to iso) dmg files.

-Built in burner functionality to burn ISO and dmg files directly to CD/DVD/Blu-Ray.

-Read Mac multisession and hybrid CDs.

Good luck.

Comment: No no no no no that's not what I want. I want to go to Mac, and mount a DMG. So now Mac has one more "disc", i.e. virtual disc, mounted on the system. Just like when I plug in a USB hard drive, only this drive is virtual. Okay? So now Mac has one more drive. Then I open the VMWare window, in which Windows 8.1 is running all the time. I want that virtual Windows to recognize that host OS has one more drive, as if I plugged a drive into Windows. Am I explaining this in a good way?

Comment: As I said in my original reply, a windows o/s, virtual or otherwise can not natively mount/open a .dmg.  The software I posted is installed on the windows o/s.  With it you 'can' then mount/open .dmg's.  I just downloaded and installed the transmit software and it works as advertised.

Comment: DMG gets mounted in OS X, not Windows. Windows should only be informed (by the virtual machine) that new hard drive is connected to the system. OS X accesses the DMG, and Windows sees this DMG as a simple new hard drive. Virtual machine (VMWare) translates interactions between virtual Windows and physical DMG. To illustrate this, here's an example: within virtual machine Windows can easily read and write to Mac's file system, without any additional software - because virtrual machine translates all interacions. I want the same with newly mounted DMGs.

Comment: Just because you think windows "should" be informed about the DMG does not mean it works that way.  Apple disk images (dmg) is a proprietary format.  No matter how many ways you state your case it will not change the fact that a windows o/s (virtual or otherwise) can not natively 'see' a DMG file.  You can read more about the Apple Disk Image format on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image.

Comment: OK. Let's go step by step. How does my Windows natively "see" propriatery HFS+ filesystem?

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just share a folder on the mounted DMG through the Fusion folder sharing facility?  It would appear under the Z: somewhere I believe inside the Windows VM.

Comment: Can you add some more detailed descriptions on how to do this? This would help other users not so familiar with the concept to implement the solution you are proposing

Comment: Right now I'm out of virtual machines on my system, but when I copy one back I'll definitely try this scenario.